# Unable to send and receive msg at same time in activeMQ

Tags: jakarta-ee, activemq-classic

**Problem:**  unable to send and receive msg at same time, but if i terminate one thread(consumer/Producer) then i can see msg at another end of queue.

**In Debug** it stuck on ***conn=connectionFactory.createConnection()***

**Consumer**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Consumer implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm:localhost");
        Connection conn;
        Session session = null;
        MessageConsumer consumer = null;
        try {
            conn=connectionFactory.createConnection();
            conn.setClientID("sms2");
            conn.start();
            session=conn.createSession(true,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            //create topic or queue
            Destination destination=    session.createQueue("sms.one");
            //create message consumer
            consumer=session.createConsumer(destination);
            consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener(){

                public void onMessage(Message msg) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(msg instanceof ObjectMessage){
                        ObjectMessage objMsg=(ObjectMessage) msg;
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Received: " + ((Notification)objMsg.getObject()).getName());
                            System.out.println("Received Time: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd:mm:yy").format(new Date(objMsg.getJMSTimestamp())));
                        } catch (JMSException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }


            });
            //Message msg=consumer.receive();
            /*if(msg instanceof ObjectMessage){
                ObjectMessage objMsg=(ObjectMessage) msg;
                System.out.println("Received: " + ((Notification)objMsg.getObject()).getName());
                System.out.println("Received Time: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd:mm:yy").format(new Date(objMsg.getJMSTimestamp())));
            }*/

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{


        }


    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
}
}
```

**Producer**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Producer implements Runnable
{

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory=new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm:localhost");
        try {
            Connection conn=factory.createConnection();
            conn.setClientID("sms1");
            conn.start();
            Session session=conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            Destination dest=session.createQueue("sms.one");

            MessageProducer producer=session.createProducer(dest);

            //producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
            //producer.setTimeToLive(timeToLive);
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                ObjectMessage objMsg=session.createObjectMessage();
                Notification notification=new Notification();
                notification.setName("Bonjour, j'aaple suresh");
                objMsg.setObject(notification);
                //objMsg.setJMSTimestamp(10000);
                producer.send(objMsg);

                System.out.println("message has been send" +objMsg);
                System.out.println("send time : " +new SimpleDateFormat("dd:mm:yy").format(new Date(objMsg.getJMSTimestamp())));
            }producer.close();
            session.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Producer()).start();
    }
/*  
    new MessageListener() {
        public void onMessage(Message message) {

                if (message instanceof ActiveMQMessage) {
                    ActiveMQMessage activeMessage = (ActiveMQMessage) message;
                    Object command = activeMessage.getDataStructure();
                    if (command instanceof ConsumerInfo) {
                        System.out.println("A consumer subscribed to a topic or queue: " + command);
                    } else if (command instanceof RemoveInfo) {
                        RemoveInfo removeInfo = (RemoveInfo) command;
                        if (removeInfo.isConsumerRemove()) {
                            System.out.println("A consumer unsubscribed from a topic or queue");
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("RemoveInfo, a connection was closed: " + command);
                        }
                    } else if (command instanceof ConnectionInfo) {
                        System.out.println("ConnectionInfo, a new connection was made: " + command);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Unknown command: " + command);
                    }
                }*/
}
```

**Notification**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Notification implements Serializable {
     /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String name  ;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**activemq.xml**

```
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

         <destinations>
            <queue physicalName="sms.one" />

    </destinations>

        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
            <!--<jdbcPersistenceAdapter  dataDirectory="activemq-data"
                dataSource="#postgresDS" lockKeepAlivePeriod="0"/>-->
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>



    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

    <bean id="postgresDS" class="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource">
            <property name="serverName" value="127.0.0.1"/>
            <property name="databaseName" value="activemq"/>
            <property name="portNumber" value="54321"/>
            <property name="user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="dataSourceName" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="initialConnections" value="2"/>
            <property name="maxConnections" value="5"/>
        </bean>
</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: First try the broker URL as `vm://localhost`

Comment: ** Exception ** 
org.apache.activemq.store.SharedFileLocker  - Database activemq-data\sms_brocker\KahaDB\lock is locked... waiting 10 seconds for the database to be unlocked. Reason: java.io.IOException: File 'activemq-data\sms_brocker\KahaDB\lock' could not be locked.

Comment: I have the same problem while trying to test ActiveMQ functionality. I am running a producer and consumer from the same Eclipse project on OSX and I get the "could not be locked" exception. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: It is because I was using consumer and subscriber on same DB (KAHADB). KAHAdb is like file based so at a time only one process can access using lock. 
Try to put both on different system/process or use some database other rather than kahadb. because both of the process or thread will try to access it and one thread will create a lock on the db file. 
So it will throw the exception.